# Combine logical operator table with vector to produce list of combinations

Tags: r, apply

I have a logical table that looks like this:

```
Var1  Var2  Var3
FALSE FALSE FALSE
FALSE TRUE  FALSE
TRUE  FALSE TRUE
TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

etc.

and a vector that has strings:

e.g. `c('a', 'b', 'c')`

where the length of the string matches the number of columns in the logical table.

In BASE R only, how can I get an output as a list such that the output looks like:

```
$1 [1] character(0)   # empty
$2 [1] "b"
$3 [1] "a" "c"        # TRUE positions matched to vector positions
$4 [1] "a" "b" "c"
```

in effect, reproducing the plyr package call *mlply*

e.g. code using **plyr** package

```
myset <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
n<-length(myset)
logicaltable <- expand.grid(replicate(n, list(c(F,T))))
mlply(logicaltable, function(...) { myset[c(...)] })
```

Comment: Could you give a mock-up of your desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in Base R with the following line of code:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) c('a', 'b', 'c')[x])
```

What this is doing is essentially subsetting the vector `c('a', 'b', 'c')` by each row in your dataframe (meaning each row is treated like a vector) and returning a list. For example, for the second row, this happens:

```
c('a', 'b', 'c')[c(F, T, F)]
[1] "b"
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect for what I need.

Comment: Happy to help! :)